# Playing Windows system sounds from VB6

Tags: audio, vb6

I want to play Windows system sounds like those for *Error* and *Information* dialog boxes.

I tried [Beep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API:

```
Public Declare Function Beep Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal dwFreq As Long, ByVal dwDuration As Long) As Long
Beep 200, 2000
```

The problem is that it works in XP/2000 only, but not in Win 7. Also I want to be able to play *different* sounds.

Comment: A 1-second search on Google for `VB6 system sounds` turns up this [Microsoft tutorial page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/c27he2zs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as the very first result. SO is not a replacement for doing a basic search on your own first.

Comment: @Ken White Sorry ! i searched anywhere so i decided to ask here . i said i want "VB6" not ".NET" . and Microsoft tutroial is just for VB.NET and VB2010 , its not supporting Visual Basic version 6 !! Thanks for your comment .

Comment: Sorry. Had to look at a couple more articles on those search results to find [this one](http://www.pgacon.com/visualbasic.htm#Playing%20the%20Windows%20System%20Sounds) instead, which is specifically for VB6. Took a whole two minutes or so. :-) Like I said, please put *some effort* into solving things yourself before posting here. SO should not be considered your personal research assistant. We're not a LMGTFY site. :-)

Comment: Oops ! That worked fine ! :D Thank you alot. Mr.Ken i Really searched it about 1-2 hours on the Google ! (`"System Sounds in VB6"`) But i didn't get any result ! Thank you again !

Comment: @AmirrezA_Nasiri If you have a good solution , you could post it herer as an answer for anyone that comes accross this question later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play the standard Windows alert sounds by calling the [`MessageBeep` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680356.aspx). To call it from VB 6, you'll need to write a declaration like so:

```
Public Declare Function MessageBeep Lib "user32" (ByVal wType As Long) As Long
```

And then you'll need the constants that specify the type of beep to play:

```
Public Const MB_DEFAULTBEEP As Long = -1   ' the default beep sound  
Public Const MB_ERROR As Long       = 16  ' for critical errors/problems
Public Const MB_WARNING As Long     = 48  ' for conditions that might cause problems in the future
Public Const MB_INFORMATION As Long = 64  ' for informative messages only
Public Const MB_QUESTION As Long    = 32  ' (no longer recommended to be used)
```

Notice that they match up perfectly with the icons displayed by a message box (MsgBox). Each of the available icons has a different default alert sound that is associated with it. The same [guidance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511277.aspx) that applies to the correct use of these icons in a message box also applies to their use as isolated, independent alert sounds.

And of course, because these are standard system sounds, they're not guaranteed to always play the same sounds. The exact sounds used are configurable by the user. But that's probably what you want.

---

As for why `Beep` doesn't work, it's a rather sad and complicated story. The [function documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277.aspx) contains most of the details:

> A long time ago, all PC computers shared a common 8254 programable interval timer chip for the generation of primitive sounds. The Beep function was written specifically to emit a beep on that piece of hardware.
>   [...]
>   Since then, sound cards have become standard equipment on almost all PC computers. As sound cards became more common, manufacturers began to remove the old timer chip from computers. The chips were also excluded from the design of server computers. The result is that Beep did not work on all computers without the chip. This was okay because most developers had moved on to calling the MessageBeep function that uses whatever is the default sound device instead of the 8254 chip.
>
> Eventually because of the lack of hardware to communicate with, support for Beep was dropped in Windows Vista and Windows XP 64-Bit Edition.
>
> In Windows 7, Beep was rewritten to pass the beep to the default sound device for the session. This is normally the sound card, except when run under Terminal Services, in which case the beep is rendered on the client.

You can find even more information on Larry Osterman's blog: [What's up with the Beep driver in Windows 7?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2010/01/04/what-s-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7.aspx)

So it *should* be working on Windows 7, but it requires that your computer has sound generator hardware installed, that you have speakers connected, and that they're turned on. Of course, so does the `MessageBeep` function.